# Android Audio Streaming is too slow

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I'm trying to make a radio app. Everything is ok, except playing radios. I'm getting play link from a page with Jsoup. When i press play, (in real device)it takes 40-50 seconds to start playing. But in genymotion device (Google Nexus 4- 4.4.4- API 19) it takes just 3-4 second. I couldn't find what is wrong.

I'm new on Android and I couldn't find a solution for days. Thanks id advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend you to use google exo player instead of default android player for streaming. its too fast and you will never have problems like this.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I couldn't figure out how to import exoplayer on my project :( Do you know a good tutorial shows how to do it step by step?

Comment: you can download and import the project in android studio to run the demo .also you can use https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html and https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

Comment: really thank you so much, it worked. One more question, do you know a way how can I make custom design for mediacontroller?

Answer (score 1):

You must try it without emulator, as they themselves are slow.

Also give below links a read.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

For Best performance native is good:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/index.html

Comment: thanks for answer, I used exoplayer and problem solved.